# Do target=_blank URIs still pass on referrer data?

Tags: html, http, seo, http-headers

I'm interested in using target=_blanks for links but as I don't want to do parameterized URIs I am worried about losing request-based data such as the referrer. Is that fear misplaced?

Comment: if i remember well, IE6 doesn't know to read reffers in blank windows.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Yes, referrer data is passed when targeting '_blank':

```
<a href="link" target="_blank">text</a>
```

Comment: can you cite a source?

Comment: Doesn't work for me in the latest chrome. Using `document.referer` in the Chrome console returns an empty string.

Comment: If this used to work, it no longer appears to. And I don't think it's browser specific. I've got several links to my site right now from a popular blog. They all used `target=_blank` on the links. None of them pass a referrer on. Checked in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: wrong answer, referrer data is not passed when using target="_blank"

Answer (score 13):

No. You can try this in the latest chrome by pasting the following into the address bar:

`data:text/html, <a href="http://darwinandsierra.com" target="_blank">text</a>`

Then click the link, open the Chrome console and type:

`document.referer`

It returns a blank string.

Comment: Yes, of course, as the document containing the link does not have a URL - it was opened from a data: source.

Answer (score 3):

All links pass referrer data, unless you manually configure your browser to not send that info.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a "don't" somewhere in the last part of the sentence?